# 7zip command line how do i add the l next to x

Tags: 7-zip

i have this command that works however i want to list contents in zip so i need to add l command to it but i already have x so am stuck.

this code extracts a file from zip but i need to add l next to x so that i can se content list.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z" x "C:\Users\sarah\Downloads\MAME\MAME_2010_full_nonmerged_romsets\roms\*.zip" -o"C:\Users\sarah\Desktop\rom test\New folder (2)\" *41_gfx7.rom -y -aoa
```

or maybe how do i search all subfolders alswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to use `l` and `x` at the same time. Use `l` instead of `x`. You get one command (e.g., `l` for list or `x` for extract), but may be able to use multiple options.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z" l "C:\Users\user1\Downloads\MAME\MAME_2010_full_nonmerged_romsets\roms\*.zip" *41_gfx7.rom
```

The output directory (`-o"C:\Users\user2\Desktop\rom test\New folder (2)\"`), overwrite mode (`-aoa`), and automatically choosing affirmatively (`-y`, for saying yes to prompts) don't apply as much, if at all, when listing.  So, just drop those options that aren't applicable.

Comment: so cant i run the command extract while it searches through each file,so that i can add a code to vb6 to check if file is found so i can stop the cmd.

Comment: this command of mine "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z" x "C:\Users\sarah\Downloads\MAME\MAME_2010_full_nonmerged_romsets\roms\*.zip" -o"C:\Users\sarah\Desktop\rom test\New folder (2)\" *41_gfx7.rom -y -aoa     how can i add code so i can add 1 root folder so it checks every folder and files in that 1 folder.

Comment: First of all, when you say "checks", do you mean "list contents" instead of extract?  If so, make it say "7z l" instead of "7z x".  Second, do you mean a root folder on your filesystem or a "root folder" within the ZIP file?  This is important because one can be done using FOR and the other using FIND or FINDSTR.  Finally, I point out that your question about the root folder is different than your question about how to use l to list files, so that should actually be asked in a separate question on superuser, so we can answer it separately.  (Multi-question questions are quite undesirable.)